# Why is only one device being allowed on the Internet through my Asus router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

Only one specific device (always the same one laptop) is able to connect to the internet. I did a factory reset but the problem still happens. The other devices (Android, Symbian, another laptop) can connect to Wi-Fi, but cannot connect to the internet. Two weeks ago there wasn't any problem with the devices mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

This can happen when your Wi-Fi "router" is actually just bridging, and your broadband modem latches onto the first LAN-side MAC address it sees after it boots. DOCSIS-compliant cable modems are especially likely to do this to you.

The solution is to put your Wi-Fi router back into NAT gateway mode and make sure your Wi-Fi router's WAN port (not its LAN port) is the only thing connected to the LAN side of the cable modem.  Then fully power down the cable modem and then boot it back up. That the router's WAN MAC address will be the one the cable modem latches onto, because no other machine's MAC address will be visible to the cable modem.

Note: If your cable modem includes telephone gateway functionality (VoIP, "digital voice", eMTA, etc.), it may have a built-in battery backup, so when you unplug the cable modem, be sure to look to see if you need to also unplug the backup battery in order to fully power-down the unit.

Note also that accidentally connecting one of your Wi-Fi router's LAN ports to the cable modem can have this same effect, as it means that the Wi-Fi router will simply be bridging your LAN/WLAN traffic over to the cable modem, so all your devices' MAC addresses will be visible to the cable modem. So if someone accidentally (re-)connected a cable to the wrong port, just switch it back to the WAN port.

Comment: Accidentally connecting your WAN (Internet connection) to one of your router's WAN ports will do this.

Comment: Can you tell me, how to put my Asus wifi router into NAT gateway mode?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy fix...sounds lame but i did it this way
So i have 4 devices
2 android 1 ios and 1 windows laptop
Wifi network was available on only one android and it showed "no internet access" on other devices.. now do this
1- disconnect the device that has wifi access 
2- turn off wifi on all other devices
3- restart the router
4- thats it you have wifi on all devices

This worked for me...hope it does for you too :D

Comment: I tried doing this and it kind of switched the wifi on one of the other devices and it got it on the new device but then the one that originally had it lost it. I am debugging a Zoom brand combo router-modem and it's not currently configurable. Thanks for the ideas though

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution but had no effect.  I called Asus technical support and they were able to identify and correct my issue.  The problem arose within windows from renaming the routers SSID.  Windows 7 was keeping the previous and the new name of the router in the list of available networks (found here):

Control Panel\Network and Internet\Manage Wireless Networks

There were several instances of the renamed router after I had reset and renamed the device.  This was the root cause of the error.  I deleted both the old and new instances of the router.  Then I logged on to the renamed router again - had to enter the encryption key and presto - it worked as expected.  Not sure why this particular router created a problem with the renaming protocol as I've never had this happen before even with a Asus router. If you are stuck - give this a shot!

Answer (score 0):

My Solution for my X9000 that was having this issue was call the ISP.

I was only able to connect with one IP at a time through their service.
After calling and speaking with their tech support, I found that my firmware update turn off my IPv6 that was limiting my connection access.

So the ISP dropped all the additional IPv4 that I had been loading, did some behind the screen magic on their end and the router started to work as it was intended.